# FullCalendar - save events in cookie

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to create a FullCalendar with the external dragging functionality where you can save the events added to the calendar in a cookie (I'd have much prefered to save this on the server, but that's not an option). I'm using jquery cookie plugin to make it easier.

What I've got so far is the save functionality (which I believe is working):

> ```
> function save() {
>     var eventsFromCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
>     $.cookie("DSCalendar", eventsFromCalendar, {expires: 1});
> }
> ```

...But I can't get the calendar to include this when I next open it. I've tried doing it like this but it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     ....

        var savedEvents = $.cookie("DSCalendar");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: savedEvents,
             ...........
```

Any chance there's anyone out there who has done this before or have any idea of how I can get the events saved without using a server?

Comment: What's the value of savedEvents if you debug this? Also you might want to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to store and retrieve this object from the cookie. `$.cookie("DSCalendar", JSON.stringify(eventsFromCalendar), {expires: 1});` and `var savedEvents = JSON.parse($.cookie("DSCalendar"));` I had a similar issue - but I was using LocalStorage instead of cookies.

Comment: @ganeshk - The savedEvents value is `[object Object]` for each event that has been saved, which isn't quite right. Adding JSON.stringify/parse gave me `{"length":1,"0":{},"context":{"jQuery17108956974661894247":1,"location":{}},"selector":"#calendar"}` and the calendar does not show on the page. Did you find an easy way of doing it with LocalStorage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookie plugin can't store complex object arrays I think. That's why I suggested using `JSON.stringify`. However, the Object array returned by `.fullCalendar('clientEvents')` contains recursive Object references - so even `JSON.stringify` fails to convert this successfully.

Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/v6tSd/

I created a temp Object array before storing it in the cookie and then `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` worked perfectly.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful - although I went for localStorage in the end as the cookies didn't seem to save it properly. It's finally working!

Answer (score 0):

In FullCalendar v1, the contents of clientEvents includes a key-object pair called "source" for each event, if you are loading your data remotely.  That pair has the URL of the remote data in it, which returns the error "Converting circular structure to JSON" if you try to stringify clientEvents in order to save or send it to a location that needs a string, not an array of objects.  The work around that I used is to remove the "source" key and object with the following script:

```
var eventsFromCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
for (var i = 0; i < eventsFromCalendar.length; i++) {
    delete eventsFromCalendar[i].source
    }
var jstrng = JSON.stringify(eventsFromCalendar);
```